# Should this question be considered "idea generation" and closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

This question apparently doesn't have a single correct answer: [What are some monsters that could trap NPCs for a long time without killing them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/206825/)

On the other hand, it is pretty narrow for being "idea generation". Is this question on-topic?

Related: [How can we distinguish "idea generation" questions from "asking for a solution" ones?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11643/)

Answer (score 5):

Very borderline but possibly salvageable, IMO.

I think the current phrasing of things, especially the title, *does* veer too close to idea generation. "What are some" is a yellow-flag of a phrase, but not always unrecoverable.

If the core question is, "Due to a time dilation effect, I need ways to hold human captives for excessive amounts of time without aging and dying", as I read it, that can be made stackable by limiting to published sources and doing a phrasing tidy-up.